# Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow на русском!

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Когда пишу ответ вылезает вот это

> Ваш ответ
>
> Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow на русском!
>
> Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your
>   research! But avoid …
>
> Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers. Making
>   statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal
>   experience. To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.

Вы б перевели а то сайт русский все таки ;)

Comment: Практически весь интерфейс сайта уже переведен. Бывает, что переводы слетают. Чаще всего это происходит, когда изменена оригинальная строка.

Comment: Проверьте пожалуйста, на каком языке сейчас это сообщение?

Comment: Мне уже не показывается

Comment: понял. Будем искать того, кому показывается )

Comment: @NickVolynkin любому, открывшему страницу в приватном режиме.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Текст переведён:

> [image: Спасибо за ответ]

Comment: @Grundy переведено уже давно. Просто я решил посмотреть вопросы [meta-tag:статус-воспроизведено] и подобные. Модераторы бездействуют! :)

Comment: наказать их!!!!